# Could not Create "Run Configuration" for a Javascript Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, protractor, eclipse-indigo

Installed Javascript eclipse (Indigo). Installed Node.js and protractor. Have created a JavaScript project. Added sample.js file. Tried to create a Run configuration. But could not find "Node Js Application" configuration in "Run configurations" tab. How to get the Node js configuration in the list.

tried installing javascript plugins from "Help->Install new software" and from market

**Actual Result:**
Getting below list of configurations in "Run configuration" dialog.
HTTP Preview,
Java Applet,
Java Application,
XSL

**Expected Result:**
Require other run configurations like:
Node.js application

Comment: Eclipse Indigio is 8 years and 9 releases out of date. Try using something more up to date such as the current release 2019-03.

Comment: Indigo is extremely old and you won't get any support for it. Try installing the latest release (Eclipse IDE 2019-03) and adding https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide as plugin in it for good node.js support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing "eclipse-javascript-oxygen-3-win32" on my windows 7 32 bit. 
It fixed the issue.